# Изменить описание коммита слияния

Tags: git, git-merge

Подскажите, как задать свое описание для коммита слияния? При git merge коммит сохраняется в истории с описанием вроде "Merge branch 'master' into 'dev'".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый легкий способ изменить сообщение предыдущего коммита:

`git commit --amend -m "текст"`

Можно запретить при merge автоматический коммит через `--no-commit` и потом задать текст коммита самому

```
git merge <branch A> --no-commit
git commit -m "текст"
```